# Is there a way to get all database names in MarkLogic server in XQuery?

Tags: database, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to show all database names in a MarkLogic server. However, the functions that I found are:

```
admin:database-get-name(database ID)
xdmp:database(database name)
xdmp:database(database ID)
```

They all require a know piece of information about the database. So is there a way to retrieve all database names without knowing there IDs?
or is there a way to retrieve the IDs of all databases in the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. [xdmp-databases()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:databases) with [xdmp:database-name()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-name)

Long-hand clear example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
  let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db-id)
  order by $db-name
  return $db-name
```

or quick-n-dirty:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare option xdmp:mapping "true";

xdmp:database-name(xdmp:databases())
```

Comment: Note that the quick-n-dirty solution depends on function mapping (`declare option xdmp:mapping "true"`). The FLWOR approach is more robust in that sense. You could also leverage XQuery 3.0 mapping, but that is only available with `xquery version "1.0-ml";` or `xquery version "3.0";`: `xdmp:databases() ! xdmp:database-name(.)`

Comment: Thank Geert.  I've changed the samples to be clear about the explicit need of xdmp:mapping